# How to save data in SQL that use Data-Retrieval Functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-retrieval

I am retreiving values from a Table which in turn i am comparing with values from another table using the SQL keywords 'EXCEPT'

My query looks something like follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TDC_TREE_FAMILY_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level1,
                TDC_TREE_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level2,
                TDC_TREE_SUB_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level3 
                FROM TD_DATA_PACK_CONTENTS
                EXCEPT
SELECT  DPC_Level1,DPC_Level2,DPC_Level3 FROM DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES
ORDER BY DPC_Level1
```

Now this query works fine . What i want to do is save the results in a single string variable.

So I declare 3 temps variables to save the values of DPC_Level1,Lvl2,Lvl3 and then i can join them into a single string variable.

So i modify my Query like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT @m_DPC_Level11=TDC_TREE_FAMILY_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level1
               ,@m_DPC_Level2=TDC_TREE_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level2,
               ,@m_DPC_Level13=TDC_TREE_SUB_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level3 
                FROM TD_DATA_PACK_CONTENTS
                EXCEPT
SELECT  DPC_Level1,DPC_Level2,DPC_Level3 FROM DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES
ORDER BY DPC_Level1
```

But this throws the error

> 'A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations'

. How i resolve this issue. I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a subquery

```
select @m_DPC_LEvel11 = DPC_Level1,
       @m_DPC_Level2  = DPC_Level2,
       @m_DPC_Level13 = DPC_Level3,
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TDC_TREE_FAMILY_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level1,
                TDC_TREE_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level2,
                TDC_TREE_SUB_CLASSIFICATION AS DPC_Level3 
                FROM TD_DATA_PACK_CONTENTS
                EXCEPT
    SELECT  DPC_Level1,DPC_Level2,DPC_Level3 FROM DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES
    ORDER BY DPC_Level1) s
```